# WebView2 Download progress

Tags: c#, winforms, download, webview2

Need to get download progress via WebView2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2downloadoperation?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.865-prerelease

```
async void InitializeAsync()
{
  var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\EdgeCore\92.0.887.0");
  await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
  webView.CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting += webView_DownloadStarting;
  webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("downloadURL");
}

private void webView_DownloadStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
{           
  e.ResultFilePath = filename;
  public event EventHandler<object> BytesReceivedChanged; <-- Need this event for print bytes to webView_BytesReceivedChanged
  public event EventHandler<object> StateChanged; <-- Need this event for print download state to webView_StateChanged
}

private void webView_BytesReceivedChanged(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.DownloadOperation.BytesReceived); // Bytes received
  Console.WriteLine(e.DownloadOperation.TotalBytesToReceive); // Total bytes to receive
}

private void webView_StateChanged(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.DownloadOperation.State); //2 Completed, 1 In progress, 0 Error
}
```

I tried:

```
public event EventHandler BytesReceivedChanged;
BytesReceivedChanged += webView_BytesReceivedChanged;
```

but event never fired

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note** (to others reading this): This requires version '**1.0.865-prerelease**' or later. First subscribe to the `CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting`event. You can do that in the `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted`eventhandler or like shown above.

Now in the `CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting` eventhandler you save a reference to the `CoreWebView2DownloadOperation`and subscribe to the `BytesReceivedChanged` and `EstimatedEndTimeChanged`.

**Here is the code** (assuming your `WebView2` is called 'webView21'):

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

CoreWebView2DownloadOperation downloadOperation;

private void WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView21.CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting += CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting;
}

private void CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
{
    downloadOperation = e.DownloadOperation; // Store the 'DownloadOperation' for later use in events
    downloadOperation.BytesReceivedChanged += DownloadOperation_BytesReceivedChanged; // Subscribe to BytesReceivedChanged event
    downloadOperation.EstimatedEndTimeChanged += DownloadOperation_EstimatedEndTimeChanged; // Subsribe to EstimatedEndTimeChanged event
}

private void DownloadOperation_EstimatedEndTimeChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    label1.Text = downloadOperation.EstimatedEndTime.ToString(); // Show the progress
}

private void DownloadOperation_BytesReceivedChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    label2.Text = downloadOperation.BytesReceived.ToString(); // Show the progress
}
```

Now the labels will show the progress.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer from you. Works like a charm! Thank you very much from pain. :-)