# WebView2 file download notification box

Tags: webview2

I have what seems like a stupid problem. I have been working on a WebView2 app for a couple of days now. Prior to today, when I would download a file within the app, I would get the usual download notification box in the lower left. Now I'm getting this popup window on the upper right. I don't know what has changed. I've gone back to old code in which I didn't see this behavior and it does it there also. I need to move it back to the lower left. Does anyone know what I have done or how to change this back? Thanks for any help. Kevin.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take full control of the dialog (I don't think you can easily just move it).

You do that by subscribing to the `CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting` event:
[`CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.downloadstarting?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49).

The `CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs` has a property `DownloadOperation` (see [`CoreWebView2DownloadOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2downloadoperation?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49) giving you access to the progress.

Here you can totally define, what should happen, in your case showing a progress dialog.

To see an example of this, you can check my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537998/webview2-download-progress)

Comment: Thanks, this led me to what I needed. I found the Handled property in the CoreWebVFiew2DownloadStartingEventArgs. This lets me remove the default download notification entirely. I'm already tapping into the DownloadOperation StateChanged event to do some custom handling of the file that is downloaded so this fits right in.

Answer (score 2):

The Edge browser and the WebView2 Runtime updated the download UX to what you see now. The [WebView2 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes#10955-prerelease) note this happened near July 26, 2021.

The download UX is implemented in the WebView2 Runtime. If you have an older Fixed Version copy of the WebView2 Runtime you would be able to see the old download UX. Changing the WebView2 SDK version will not change which download UX you get.

This is the default download UX for WebView2. You can replace it with your own custom download UX using the [`CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.downloadstarting?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49) and associated APIs.

Comment: I was coming to the conclusion the cause was some kind of underlying update outside of my code. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Can we switch off this window from showing all together?

Comment: Yes, `CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs.Handled` set to `true` will turn off the default download UX. Its the first step in doing custom UX, turn off the default and then show your own.